# TCP segment without options and data

Tags: c, networking

I want to implement a simplified TCP/IP stack. Now I am  writting my `tcp_connect` function.
In the handshake step, can I send the TCP segment without TCP options and data(Only send the TCP header in the client side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any options are required. However, it you don't send the Maximum Segment Size option, the default MSS that's assumed is only 576.

TCP handshaking segments don't usually include any data. However, it's legal to include it, so your stack should accept it if it receives it.

Answer (score 0):

There is only three (simple for implementation) options described in [RFC793:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1)

> ```
>   Kind     Length    Meaning
>   ----     ------    -------
>    0         -       End of option list.
>    1         -       No-Operation.
>    2         4       Maximum Segment Size.
> ```

You can try to append only "End of option list" to TCP header, or use predefined template.

As a client, you may not add data in outgoing handshake-segments, but you should be able to process incoming ones when you accept connection.

---

> I tried as you saied, but cannot get response.

Did you try to use something like TCPdump on other side? Any incoming segments?

Comment: I open a tfp server on the destination PC, then try to connect to it.That's the test method I am using.

Comment: Here is my tcp head I have sent `dc a9 00 15 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 02 39 08 f9 7c 00 00 00 00 00 00`,I capture it from the server side,but still no response.And I have add the `End of option list`.

Comment: I'v check your header, and got next values: 
`Source port: 43484`
`Dest. port: 5376 `
Seq Num: 1
Ack Num: 0

Flags:
|  Data |         |E|C|U|A|P|R|S|F|
| Offset| Reserved|C|W|R|C|S|S|Y|I|
|       |         |C|R|G|K|H|T|N|N|
  0000      0010   0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

Window: 2105
Checksum: 31993
UP: 0
+End-Of-Options marker
`

Some values seems to be wrong (especially flag field).
May be problems with byte ordering?

Comment: Nope! Your TCP-header is legal. My bad.

Comment: Then  why I can not get connected?

Comment: I used `wireshark` to capture the datagram, found nothing wrong in the  head.Please help me!

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin, is underlaying layer right? May be problem in it?

Comment: I forget to turn the length in pseudo head to network sequence,after correct it,I get a response.Sorry for trouble caused.